# Java - Escape HTML characters excluding some characters

Tags: java, html, regex

I'm trying to escape special characters in my HTML code except the characters used in tags (<, >, ", ', and &). I tried searching for existing libraries(i.e `StringEscapeUtils`) for this but all of them also escapes <, >, ", ', and & - characters I don't want to escape.

For example, if I have

```
<div>— £</div>
```

I want it to be converted to

```
<div>&mdash; &pound;</div>
```

I DON'T want it to be

```
&lt;div&gt;&mdash; &pound;&lt;/div&gt;
```

Is there any way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Add this class to your code. (The package is necessary since the code uses some package-scoped names.)

```
package org.apache.commons.lang;

public class Fix extends Entities {
    public static final Entities HTML04;
    static {
        HTML04 = new Entities();
        HTML04.addEntities(ISO8859_1_ARRAY);
        HTML04.addEntities(HTML40_ARRAY);
    }
    public static String escapeHtml(String str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return HTML04.escape(str);
    }
}
```

It is now possible to escape HTML without `<, >, &, "` using

```
String html = "<div> & — £ \"</div>
Fix.escapeHtml(html)
```

Output:

```
<div> & &mdash; &pound; "</div>
```